# How to make Drag&Drop work?

Tags: c#, winforms, event-handling

I have a textbox on a winform in Visual Studio. I want to drag&drop files on it. This is what I have done:

```
public LangMerge()
{   InitializeComponent();
    this.AllowDrop = true;
    tbxFilepath.AllowDrop = true;
    tbxFilepath.DragDrop += new DragEventHandler(tbxFilepath_DragDrop);
    tbxFilepath.DragEnter += new DragEventHandler(tbxFilepath_DragEnter);
}
void tbxFilepath_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    string[] files = (string[])e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop);
    foreach (string file in files) tbxFilepath.Text=(file);
}
void tbxFilepath_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop)) e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy;
}
```

Neither the drag effect nor the receiving of the file does not work. No error messages or warnings. What could be the problem?

UPDATE: I inserted breakpoints into the event handler methods and the code doesn't get into them in the first place, no matter what I do with the cursor.

Comment: Works fine.  Crystal ball says that you are running VS elevated.  So your program runs elevated as well.  You cannot drag from a non-elevated app like Explorer into an elevated one.  Restart VS and run it normally.

Comment: Strange because I'm not running it as admin. How can I run it w/o elevated permissions?

Answer (score 0):

You have set `AllowDrop=true;` and handled `DragDrop()` and `DragEnter()` events, however for winforms application you need to also handle `TextBox.DragOver()` event :

Something like this :

```
private void textBoxFile_DragOver(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
   if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop))
     e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy;
   else
     e.Effect = DragDropEffects.None;
 }
```

Comment: You can try either try these 2 options : Check elevated permissions in your project properties or make an exe file of your application and try dragging in that.

Comment: You may accept the answer if it works for you. It might help others. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you, but my code, as it turned out, was OK. The problem lies elsewhere.